I get UNAVAILABLE error when I try to call Firebase Cloud Function in React Native Android App
I get UNAVAILABLE error all the time when I try to call Firebase Cloud Function in React Native Android App.
I installed React Native Firebase exactly as it is described here:
https://rnfirebase.io/
I asked ChatGPT and Claude where can be a error but none of them see any error, they just repeat the manual from https://rnfirebase.io/
Just don't have any other ideas what may be wrong.
Please advise.
P. S. When I run exactly the same React Native code on iOS everything works fine. The problem is only on Android. So I think the problem is with some Android app settings in the project, not with React Native code.

Can you share the steps/documents you followed to set up your project?

@RoopaM sure:
I downloaded google-services.json from Firebase.
Inside of my /android/build.gradle file I added:
buildscript {
dependencies {
// ... other dependencies
// NOTE: if you are on react-native 0.71 or below, you must not update
//       the google-services plugin past version 4.3.15 as it requires gradle >= 7.3.0
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
// Add me --- /
}
}
in /android/app/build.gradle file:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line
